# how to handle an exception in trigger?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, triggers

I know this question may be possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462800/how-to-handle-errors-in-a-trigger?rq=1).But i didn't clear my confusion by this question.  In SQL, we use a trigger for operation on database such as insert,update,delete queries.but how can we handle an exception occured in After insert statement in trigger?  For Example..

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerAfterInsert ON Employee 
FOR INSERT
AS
declare @empid int;
declare @empname varchar(100);
declare @empsal decimal(10,2);
declare @audit varchar(100);

select @empid=i.Emp_ID from inserted i; 
select @empname=i.Emp_Name from inserted i; 
select @empsal=i.Emp_Sal from inserted i;   
set @audit='Inserted Record -- After Insert Trigger.';

insert into Employee_Audit
       (Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Emp_Sal,Audit_Action,Audit_Timestamp) 
values(@empid,@empname,@empsal,@audit_action,getdate());

PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger executed.'
GO
```

In Above insert query when I set text value rather than integer to empid, i.e. @empid=a then it throws an exception in trigger,I dont know how to handle these exception,Can anyone suggest me about this problem?

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `select @empid=i.Emp_ID from inserted i` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: What is the Data Type of Emp_ID column in Employee table? If it is INT and you are trying to insert 'a', the statement fails and trigger does not execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:
**When Creating**

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Ins_Test_Trig ON dbo.Test_Trig
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        INSERT INTO Test_Trig2
        SELECT id + 1 FROM INSERTED
        COMMIT TRANSACTION 
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO Trig_Error
    SELECT *,'err' FROM inserted

    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Example:
**When Altering**

```
ALTER TRIGGER tr_Ins_Test_Trig ON dbo.Test_Trig
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        INSERT INTO Test_Trig2
        SELECT id + 1 FROM INSERTED
        COMMIT TRANSACTION 
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

    DECLARE @Trig_Error TABLE(
    id INT, col CHAR(3)
    );

    INSERT INTO @Trig_Error
    SELECT *,'err' FROM inserted

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO Trig_Error
    SELECT * FROM @Trig_Error

    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

his is more like handling a case via a procedure.

This is an example of exception handling using a user-defined exception:

```
DECLARE
v_cnt NUMBER;
count_more_than_one EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
select count(*) into v_cnt
from whatever 
where whatever;

if v_cnt > 1 then
raise count_more_than_one;
else
whatever;
end if;
EXCEPTION
when count_more_than_one then
dbms_output.put_line('Some error message you can build here or up above');

when no_data_found then
this is a built-in exception;
END;
```